# PySpark deleted written CSV after job finished

Tags: python, pyspark

I've literally ran the below that generates a bunch of CSVs for a dataframe:

```py
df.write.csv(path, mode="overwrite", header=True, quoteAll=True)
```

I see the files being generated and updating whilst the script is running. After some hours of the script running it converts the prefixed `attempt-` folders to `task-` and then all of a sudden they disappear! Real need to find these files, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've never used PySpark -- only ever written to CSV using Pandas.  Perhaps try using
`df.toPandas().to_csv('yourfilehere.csv')` to regenerate your CSV files if you can for now as a workaround?

[toPandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas.html)

[to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: Would've loved to use pandas (easy to use, lot more community support) but the dataframe is big (billions of rows) hence the Spark way